# Where is the Startup Project setting stored for a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, properties, projects-and-solutions

When I right-click my solution in the Solution Explorer and choose Properties I get a dialog where I can select the Startup Project.

I sometimes select Current selection (If it is an experimental solution with lots of projects I jump between), but most often it is a Single startup project selected, which would usually be the main WinForms applications or or Console application.

My problem is that whenever I do a treeclean with the tfpt command (Team Foundation Power Tools 2008) this setting is forgotten. So when I try to run my solution the next time, it has defaulted to some random project and I get an error stating that I cannot run a class library or something like that. Which is obvious of course. But where is this setting stored? Why is it forgotten when I do the treeclean? The solution file is still there, right? Isn't solution properties stored there?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694685/where-is-set-as-startup-defined-and-persisted-in-c-winforms-solutions

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Reference 1

[Arian Kulp](http://www.ariankulp.com/archive/2009/02/23/2557.aspx) says:

> I was struggling with trying to figure
> out why a certain solution of mine
> wasn’t starting right.  It was in VB
> with four projects.  Upon initial open
> it would set a certain project with a
> DLL output as startup.  If I set the
> EXE as startup project, it was fine,
> but when I distribute code I always
> clean it by removing *.suo and *.user
> files, and bin/obj folders.  Upon
> opening the “cleaned” version, it
> would always revert to the DLL project
> and fail to F5 nicely.  The fix turned
> out to be simple, though I’m curious
> as to why I needed to do this at all.
>
> In the solution file, there are a list
> of pseudo-XML “Project” entries.  It
> turns out that whatever is the first
> one ends up as the Startup Project,
> unless it’s overridden in the suo
> file.  Argh.  I just rearranged the
> order in the file and it’s good.
>
> I’m guessing that C# is the same way
> but I didn’t test it.  I hope that
> this helps someone!

### Reference 2

[Setting the StartUp Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694685/where-is-set-as-startup-defined-and-persisted-in-c-winforms-solutions)

> Which project is the "startup" project only has any relevance for debugging, which means it's user metadata from the point of the solution and the projects. Regardless of which project is the "startup" project, the compiled code is the same.
>
> Because of this, the information is stored as a user setting in the Solution User Options file (solution.suo) which accompanies the Solution file (solution.sln). The .suo file "Records all of the options that you might associate with your solution so that each time you open it, it includes customizations that you have made" according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhkhh4zs.aspx).
>
> The .suo file is a binary file. If you want to read or change it programatically, you have to use [IVsPersistSolutionOpts.LoadUserOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivspersistsolutionopts.loaduseroptions.aspx) from the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop namespace.

Comment: I tried this on Visual Studio 2010 SP1, and just moving the pseudo-xml isn't enough. You also have to move the group of entries in the "GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution" group that has the GUID of the project you moved to the top. So there are two places to move lines. Don't mess with the source control info.

Comment: This is sufficient for 2019 Preview 3

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this setting is saved as part of the .suo file created whenever you edit a solution file.  This file contains various user settings, such as breakpoints, watch data etc.

I cannot confirm this but that would be my guess.

Unfortunately its not XML its a binary file and not easily edited.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a little command line utility for windows called **slnStartupProject** to solve this. It sets the Startup Project automatically like this:

```
slnStartupProject slnFilename projectName
```

I personally use it to set the project after generating the solution with [cmake](http://cmake.org) that always sets a dummy **ALL_BUILD** project as the first project in the solution.

The source is on github:

https://github.com/michaKFromParis/slnStartupProject

Forks and feedbacks are welcome.

Hope this helps!