# How do I save the start-up project I selected in VS2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, projects-and-solutions

We have a solution that is source controlled by Team System.
When we get all the files from the source control for a new computer, VS2008 chooses a random project to be the start-up project.

When changing the start-up project, the configuration is saved for the current user and doesn't update anything in the solution itself.

It seems like the selection of Start-Up project is saved locally and can't be checked-in to the source control.

Is there a way to save the default Start-Up project for a Solution in VS2008 and keep it in the source control so that every user that opens the solution will get it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer:

After checking and looking for a different solution for my solution, I found this old post: 
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238553/vs2008-where-is-the-startup-project-setting-stored-for-a-solution)

The first answer by Kirtan suggested a fix that could do the trick. He suggests to edit the .sln file in a text editor and put the project that I want as start-up project as the first project in the list.

When there is no .suo file, the first project in the list is selected as the default start-up project.

I've tried this and it works!!!

Now I can Check-in the updated .sln file and be sure that the default start-up project is the right one.

Thanks for all the help...

Answer (score 1):

The Startup Project is saved in the {SolutionName}.suo file that is in the solution's directory. The file is hidden.

Do not put this file under source control as is contains many obscure stuffs that are per user/per session.

So basically there's no way to do what you want.

Comment: I know that I shouldn't add the .suo file to the TFS. but is this the only way to select the Start-up project?

Comment: Yes it is, this settings is per-user and not per-solution.

Comment: One last thing, by default the startup project is the first in alphabetic order, declared in the solution. So if you rename the project with an underscore at the first position (e.g. "_myproject" instead of "myproject"), it will be selected by default.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change project names in this solution.